# When to use which import style for of CommonJs (node) modules in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

There seem to be different forms of import in Typescript for CommonJS (node) style modules:

If I have a pure javascript module (without an ambient definition), this seems to be fine:

```
var pureJavascript = require("pure-javascript");
```

But using `import` fails on pure javascript modules:

```
import pureJavascript = require("pure-javascript");
```

Unless I have an ambient definition for the javascript module. Then I can use

```
import * as jsWithAmbient from "js-with-ambient";
```

Provided the module exports `foo` and `bar`, I can also use

```
import {foo} from "./my-module";
import {foo, bar} from "./my-module";
import {foo as x, bar as y} from "./my-module";
```

Sometimes this seems to be the way of importing:

```
import abc from "./my-module";
```

which seems to be the same as

```
import {default as abc} form "./my-module";
```

**When to use which of the import styles?**